# TableInputFormat is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I import the `TableInputFormat` in my code as:

`import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat`

but it shows errors:

object TableInputFormat is not a member of  package org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce

but package `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce` do has the class `TableInputFormat` (http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableInputFormat.html)

And I have added the libraryDependencies including :
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.4.0""org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "2.1.1""org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "2.1.1""org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-hadoop-compat" % "2.1.1""org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.8.5"

TableInputFormat is in the `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce`
package, which is part of the `hbase-server artifact`, so it needs to add that as a dependency. But I have added that dependency, why will it run wrong?

Comment: for this kind of questions it would be helpful if you post your complete `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter the same problem, but after I add "**hbase-mapreduce**" to the pom.xml and it works well. Here my pom.xml is:

```
<!-- start of HBase-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-mapreduce -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-mapreduce</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end of hbase -->
```